# Alamofire Use of undeclared type 'Serializer'

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, serialization

I have updated to XCode 7 beta 6 and `Alamofire` needed to be updated to beta 3. In doing so, I'm having to update areas of the code that use `Alamofire`. One area in particular that I'm having difficulty updating is the code which is used to retrieve an image from a specified URL and load it into a `UIImageView`.

Previously, the extension for `Alamofire` that handled that was:

```
extension Alamofire.Request {
    class func imageResponseSerializer() -> Serializer {
        return { request, response, data in
            if data == nil {
                return (nil, nil)
            }

            let image = UIImage(data: data!, scale: UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

            return (image, nil)
        }
    }

    func responseImage(completionHandler: (NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, UIImage?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {
        return response(serializer: Request.imageResponseSerializer(), completionHandler: { (request, response, image, error) in
            completionHandler(request!, response, image as? UIImage, error)
        })
    }
}
```

But not that is throwing the error

```
Use of undeclared type 'Serializer'
```

I do realize that `Alamofire` doesn't use `Serializer` anymore, but does anyone know where I can find some documentation or examples what to do now when retrieving images?

Comment: `Serializer` was an undocumented implementation-level detail—really, just a `typealias` for a closure type that takes an `(NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse, NSData)` tuple and returns an `(AnyObject, NSError)`.

Comment: See the current implementation for getting response JSON for an idea of how to port your old code.

Comment: Also struggling to get this....did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

As you can find in the readme the serialization was rewritten.

You shoudl be able to use the method below:

```
public protocol ResponseObjectSerializable {
    init?(response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject)
}

extension Request {
    public func responseObject<T: ResponseObjectSerializable>(completionHandler: Response<T, NSError> -> Void) -> Self {
        let responseSerializer = ResponseSerializer<T, NSError> { request, response, data, error in
            guard error == nil else { return .Failure(error!) }

            let JSONResponseSerializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: .AllowFragments)
            let result = JSONResponseSerializer.serializeResponse(request, response, data, error)

            switch result {
            case .Success(let value):
                if let
                    response = response,
                    responseObject = T(response: response, representation: value)
                {
                    return .Success(responseObject)
                } else {
                    let failureReason = "JSON could not be serialized into response object: \(value)"
                    let error = Error.errorWithCode(.JSONSerializationFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
                    return .Failure(error)
                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                return .Failure(error)
            }
        }

        return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIImage serializer for Alamofire, updated for Alamofire 2.0 and Swift 2

[Alamofire 2.0 and Swift 2.0](https://gist.github.com/winzig/8bf72a6a6c4b70257dec)